# Generate image URL in model - ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I have a simple model using ActiveStorage (Rails 5.2.0.rc2), the model looks like this:

```
class Vacancy < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image

  validates_presence_of :title

  def to_builder
    Jbuilder.new do |vacancy|
      vacancy.call(self, :id, :title, :description, :created_at, :updated_at)
      vacancy.image do
        vacancy.url image.attached? ? Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image) : nil
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in the `to_builder` method I want to show the permanent URL for the image, I'm trying with `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(image)` as suggested in the rails guides (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files) but it raises this error:

`Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true`

In my application I already have the `default_url_options[:host]` set but it doesn't work, even writing `url_for(image, host: 'www.example.com')` or `url_for(image, only_path: true)` doesn't work either as it raises another error: `wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

What is the correct way to show the permanent URL in the model scope using activestorage?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Use the method `rails_blob_path` for attachements in a models and controllers

For example, if you need create a method (e.g. `cover_url`) in a model, first you should include `url_helpers` and after use method `rails_blob_path` with some parameters. You can do the same in any controller, worker etc.

Complete example below:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def cover_url 
    rails_blob_path(self.cover, disposition: "attachment", only_path: true)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

After investigate the only solution that I found is to use `url_for` with a hash of options as suggested by @DiegoSalazar, then use the `blobs` controller provided by activeresource and the correct params, ej:

`Rails.application.routes.url_for(controller: 'active_storage/blobs', action: :show, signed_id: image.signed_id, filename: image.filename, host: 'www.example.com')`

To be honest I think should be an easier way to access the permanent url of the image in the model scope, but for now is the only solution that I found.